# twig variable inside object method

Tags: symfony, twig

### Hi, I am new to Symfony and twig as well. Im trying to pass string variable as name for method. Lets have a look at the example:

```
{% for user in pagination %}
    <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
        {% for value in columns  %}
            <td>{{ user.value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This code cause an error, **method value** for object is not defined.
Variable columns contain an array of columns(id,name,email...)
Please could someone tell me correct syntax. 
 Something like:

```
<td>{{article[value]}}</td>
<td>{{article.{{value}}}}</td>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are columns value of pagination, or value is a value of user, in your example?

Comment: try to do `{{ dump(columns) }}` and paste it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference an object property on a Twig variable, under the hood the Twig engine tries to access that property on the PHP object in several ways.

Let's assume that your `user` objects are instances of a `Your\Bundle\Entity\User` class. TWIG will attempt to resolve `user.value` by trying to access the following (and I think in this order)

- `Your\Bundle\Entity\User::value()`
- `Your\Bundle\Entity\User::getValue()`
- `Your\Bundle\Entity\User::$value`

In all instances, these methods/properties must be `public` in order for Twig to access them.

In short, I don't think this is a problem in your template, but rather a problem with the underlying object.

Comment: thanks, but i want to put there value of value varible. Sounds weird

Comment: Then you'd just use `{{ value }}`

Comment: I think what he actually wants to do is dynamically call a whole series of getters on the user object, to output everything interesting using the `for` loop.  I don't think you can do that with Twig.  Perhaps an alternative would be to add a `getEverything()` method to the User object which turns all the fields in an array (associative array if you want the fieldnames too), then put the result of that into the Twig for loop.  Same principle, but you can access dynamically named methods on the PHP side.

Comment: Perhaps the attribute function? i.e., `attribute(article, value)` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html